# Mandatory service provider claims always asked and not returned in openid profile

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have added a local custom claim namely http://wso2.org/claims/fg_imprenditore to http://wso2.org/claims dialect and mapped it on a custom primary user store attribute (JDBC user store).
The custom claim appears in the user profile and I can set/update the value correctly.

I have defined a new service provider and added the custom claim in Claim Configuration -> Use Local Claim Dialect.

In addition I have edited /_system/config/oidc and modified the openid property to include the new claim as follows: sub,...,street,http://wso2.org/claims/fg_imprenditore

Now the issues.
I ask a JWT Token from a javascript client with the following request:
http://**********/?response_type=id_token&client_id=" + "f8SatEWpyi1qvPLVspsDfTbefm0a" + "&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/oauth_callback.html&nonce=" + nonce

After login the WSO2is server prompts the following message (even if the attribute is already present in the profile): You are trying to login to **** application, but it needs following information filled in the user profile. You can fill those below and proceed with the authentication. But it is advised to fill these information in your Identity Provider profile in order to avoid this step every time you login.

If I fill the field (correctly) labeled "http://wso2.org/claims/fg_imprenditore" I can proceed. In any case the claim is not returned in the JWT Token.

In addition if I go in the user profile the attribute is set correctly (with the new value!) but if I try to authenticate again I need to fill the attribute again..

Many thanks for the support.

Comment: The wso2is version is 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because "http://wso2.org/claims/fg_imprenditore" claim is not mapped to any oidc claims in WSO2 IS. Do the following in get rid of the issue.

1. Go to List under Claims in IS Management Console Main tab.
2. Click on http://wso2.org/oidc/claim
3. Add new claim with the name fg_imprenditore in oidc claim dialect. You will see a drop down to select "Mapped Local Claim". Map it to http://wso2.org/claims/fg_imprenditore. (Check "Add External Claim" section in [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Adding+Claim+Mapping))
4. Save new oidc claim and try again.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mark the claim as mandatory on your Service Provider it shouldn't request it when you try to log in. Also, in order for the jwt to contain your custom claim you need to map the custom claim to a new custom claim under the oauth dialect, and then map the new oauth claim under the oidc scope you use. It took me a while to get it too as there isn't sufficient documentation describing these steps. Hope this solves your issue.